# How can I access a class function in an iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a class:

```
class Foo
{
  std::string name_;

  Foo(std::string name)
  {
    name_ = name;
  }

  std::string getName()
  {
    return name_;
  }
}
```

I then have a populated vector of these classes:

```
std::vector<Foo *> bar_;
/* ... populate bar_ ... */
std::vector<Foo *>::iterator iter = bar_.begin();

while(iter != bar_.end())
{
  std::cout << "Name: " << (*iter)->getName() << std::endl;
}
```

My (*iter)->getName() is not working though and I get this error:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message please? Don't say you have a "vector of these classes" if that's not what you actually have, by the way. Your code looks correct; the error might be elsewhere.

Comment: Just to note, that is an infinite loop as `iter` is never incremented. Not sure if this is the actual code as semi-colon is missing from `Foo` class definition.

Comment: I'll give this a -1 for a poorly presented problem for now. If you clean it up and post real code, I'll reconsider.

Comment: @Grammin: You didn't post the actual code you're compiling.  There are several errors in your posted code, but not the one you mention.  Please post the actual code.

Comment: If you do get your code to compile, beware your loop will be infinite as you never increment iter...

Comment: @KerrekSB the problem was elsewhere in my code, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Alright then. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the member public
2. Next, if th iterator is a const_iterator (or the container is const, or both), make the member const

So

```
struct Foo
{
  std::string getName() const  { /* ... */ }
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  std::string getName() const { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: The iterator isn't const, though. Also, given that the OP has no previous problem constructing the class, access problems don't seem to be the cause of this (admittedly poorly presented) problem.